order by part of a column value
I have a table where I store user emails. I want to return values from the table ordering values by email domain.
I can do it creating a temporary table where I store just the domain of each email. But is there any other method that doesn't include creating the temporary column?
Now I have ended up with
SELECT
  email,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1) AS domain
FROM table
ORDER BY domain

that works fine as expected but creates the temporary column

Simply add the condition to the order by,
SELECT email
FROM myTable
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(email,'@',-1)  #### ASC/DESC based on your needs

See example

you are right, simply and obvious. Thank you
